# how to clear a queue routingkey binding in rabbitmq (.net)

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, message-queue

How can I clear all routing key binding from a queue in rabbitmq?

The `QueueUnbind` method need the `routingkey` `parameter`, but I just want to clear all bindings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AMQP does not allow you to do this. According to [this discussion](http://grokbase.com/t/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-discuss/126safxqef/remove-all-bindings-for-a-queue-or-list-bindings-net-client), you can workaround this by having an intermediate exchange.

Basically, you create a fanout exchange which connects directly to the exchange you are interested in. You have clients which binds queues to this intermediate exchange. When you decide you want to clear all the queues, you can simply destroy this intermediate exchange.

Comment: thanks, destroy the intermediate exchange is a good idea. And I find an other way to clear bindings, run the cmd command "rabbitmqctl list_bindings" to get all bindings, and then using the regular expression to match binding relation, the end just call QueueUnbind method.